# robot camera calibration

Tags: ros, calibration, robot, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Is there any ROS package to calibration extrinsic parameters of a camera with respect to its mounting frame?  I looked at camera_pose_calibration and camera_pose_toolkit, it seems to me that both packages do it through a second camera whose pose with respect its mounting frame or a robot (referred to as URDF cam frame) has been calibrated (i.e. a URDF cam frame is available).  My question is that how to do it without any known URDF cam frame.

Thanks in advance.

CC

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49655/robot-camera-calibration/) by [chyphen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3555/chyphen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-12-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This one:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni/Contests/ROS%203D/Automatic%20Calibration%20of%20Extrinsic%20Parameters

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2012-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0